# insert html after a certain class using append or insertAfter

Tags: jquery

Im looking to dynamically add some content to container after a certain tag,please have a look at the code below

```
<div id="simpleContainer">
  <h2 class="hDestination">Destination(s)</h2>
  <h2 class="hExtras">Extra(s)</h2>
</div>

<div id="advancedContainer">
  <h2 class="hDestination">Destination(s)</h2>
  <h2 class="hExtras">Extra(s)</h2>
</div>
```

I am trying to add some content in to the **advancedContainer** after h2 with class **hDestination** ,but it kept adding after the h2 with class **hDestination** of the simpleContainer as well.I only want the content to be added to **advancedContainer** after the h2 with class **hDestination**.

I tried the following code

```
$('<div>This is a test</div>').insertAfter('h2.hDestination','#advancedContainer');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with `.after()` it reads better and for your scenario / context is more suited:

```
$('#advancedContainer h2.hDestination').after('<div>this is a test</div>');
```

Comment: The OPs existing code was just fine ones a more specific selector was added. Is there a benefit in using `after` instead of `insertAfter` aside from preferred readability?

Comment: readability is in the eye of the beholder I guess as both read fine to me personally. Brevity I can understand, but with a 9 character in difference I don't know if it is worth changing the method posted in the original post. Regarding performance it seems `insertBefore` executes a lot faster than `insertAfter` which in turn executes faster than `after`. But then again performance might not be important at all either.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: Brevity isn't just about the difference in characters, its the repetition as well which can be avoided. The performance differences are interesting though. Also you've changed your original answer which had the same ID as a context as well. That's better as now its not repeated

Comment: Yes the repeated selector, was an accidental left-over. I only noticed when I re-checked. Regarding performance, I was quite surprised there was such a large difference in speed, the way either one of the 3 possible methods (`insertBefore`, `after` and `insertAfter`) traverses throug the DOM. I removed my answer as `pixelbobby` already had that covered (No need for 2 answers saying the same thing). See link for the test here: jsperf.com/after-vs-insertafter/3

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: Could you put up the link to the performance differences again? It was in your answer.

Comment: I added it to the comment instead now.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

`$('<div>This is a test</div>').insertAfter('#advancedContainer h2.hDestination');`

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jGPp2/1/)

...*LOL, I need to refresh the page more while fiddling...*